# asp.net image link in new window with query string parameters

Tags: asp.net, image, target

I have a page that I need to provide a link to a print version of that page, the link itself needs a picture and must open in a new window and the print page requires me to pass it a few query string parameters that vary depending on the original pages state.

I have tried a ImageButton but there doesn't seem to be a way to make it open in a new window (and still allow me to build up the query string dynamically).

I a hyperlink with an image inside (as the width of a hyperlink doesnt set the image size) but there is no click even server side for me to attach my code for query string generation.

Is there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the following in the click event of the image button and managed to get everything working

```
  ClientScriptManager objCsManager = Page.ClientScript;

            objCsManager.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "NewWindow", "<script>window.open('" + url + "', 'New')</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try building the URL in the codebehind - something like:

```
HyperLink1.NavigateURL = myMethodForBuildingUrl();
```

Where `myMethodForBuildingURl()` is whatever logic you're using to contruct the query string.

Comment: I tried this but I dont seem to be able to change the url on a postback (of another control)

Comment: At what point in the page life cycle did you try this?  I.e., Page_Load, an event handler (like button_click)?  If you can post your code in your question, I can give more suggestions.  I would think this should work, it's just a matter of when you're trying to set the property.

Comment: I tried it on the postback of a imagebutton being clicked and I also tried it on Page_PreRender just for kicks with no luck...I have found something that solved my problem see below. Thanks for the help anyway!